# PHP is possible to implode ignoring specific array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 41
    [1] => 43
    [2] => 44
    [comment] => 
)
```

is there any way to implode this array ignoring `['comment']`??

Now `['comment']`doesn't has content but sometimes it can have content. I need to ignore `['comment']` always.

Also `['comment']` will be always the last array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative offset with [`array_splice`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to remove the last element of the array.

```
$string = implode(',', array_splice($array, -1));
```

Comment: My bad, must be splice. Thank you for noticing. :)

Comment: it works because comment is the last index present in the array :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
unset($arr['comment']);
echo implode(',',$arr);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/476714)

Comment: smart solution, I've fought with this all day :(